# How can I debug this java.lang.ClassCastException that occurs when using an iterator?

Tags: java, casting, iterator, classcastexception

I am trying to separate Passenger objects from an ArrayList into eight smaller lists. I am traversing the list of Passengers using iterator.

I have tried to use the iterator without explicitly casting to the Passenger class but it does not seem to work. It prompts to cast the iterator to Passenger class, still.

Here is my Passenger class:

```
package application;

public class Passenger implements Comparable<Passenger>{

    private int key;
    private int row;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Passenger() {

    }

    public Passenger(int key, int row, String name, String type) {
        this.key = key;
        this.row = row;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    //The custom copy constructor
    public Passenger(Passenger passenger) {
        this.key = passenger.key;//This field should be null at time of instantiation
        this.row = passenger.row;
        this.name = passenger.name;
        this.type = passenger.type;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Passenger o) {
        if(this.key > o.key) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(this.key < o.key){
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //copy method
    public Passenger copy() {
        
        return new Passenger(this);
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String passengerString = String.format("%-15s%-5s%-5d%-5d", name, type, row, key);
        return passengerString;
    }
}
```

Here is the method where the exception is thrown:

```
public void loadOldPQ(ArrayList<Passenger> list) throws IOException {
        
        int priorityNumber = list.size();
        
        ArrayList<Passenger> firstGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> secondGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> thirdGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> fourthGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> fifthGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> sixthGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> seventhGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        ArrayList<Passenger> eighthGroup = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
        
        Iterator<Passenger> iter = list.iterator();
        
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
        
            if(((Passenger) iter).getType().equals("H")) {
                firstGroup.add(iter.next());
            }
            else if(((Passenger) iter).getRow() >= 1 && ((Passenger) iter).getRow() <= 4 
                    && ((Passenger) iter).getType().equals("E")){
                secondGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else if(((Passenger) iter).getRow() >= 1 && ((Passenger) iter).getRow() <= 4) {
                thirdGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else if(((Passenger) iter).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("E") || ((Passenger) iter).getRow() == 10
                    || ((Passenger) iter).getRow() == 11) {
                fourthGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else if(((Passenger) iter).getRow() >= 23 && ((Passenger) iter).getRow() <= 26) {
                fifthGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else if(((Passenger) iter).getRow() >= 17 && ((Passenger) iter).getRow() <= 22) {
                sixthGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else if(((Passenger) iter).getRow() >= 11 && ((Passenger) iter).getRow() <= 16) {
                seventhGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else if(((Passenger) iter).getRow() >= 5 && ((Passenger) iter).getRow() <= 10) {
                eighthGroup.add(iter.next());
            }else {
                System.out.println("Some error!");
            }   
        }
        
        for(Passenger passenger: firstGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: secondGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: thirdGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: fourthGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: fifthGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: sixthGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: seventhGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }
        for(Passenger passenger: eighthGroup) {
            passenger.setKey(priorityNumber);
            System.out.println(passenger);
            priorityNumber--;
        }  
}
```

The error occurs at the first if statement:

```
if(((Passenger) iter).getType().equals("H"))
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to class application.Passenger (java.util.ArrayList$Itr is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; application.Passenger is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at application.Airworthy.loadOldPQ(Airworthy.java:172)
    at application.Airworthy.readInputFile(Airworthy.java:151)
    at application.Airworthy.<init>(Airworthy.java:44)
    at application.Simulation.main(Simulation.java:20)
```

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear: the `Iterator` cannot be cast to `Passenger`. You need to call `.next()` on the `Iterator` to get the actual `Passenger`.

Comment: `Iterator<Passenger> iter = /*...*/ if(((Passenger) iter).getType().equals("H")`. An `Iterator<Passenger>` is not a `Passenger`. You cannot cast one into the other.

Comment: You are already familiar with the `for-each` loop. Why not use this approach when splitting a list of passengers in a categories lists?

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you, very much! I works perfectly now. Much simpler edit than I previously thought.

Comment: @knittl Thanks very for the tip!! I just started working with iterators, this comment helped greatly.

Comment: @chptr-one The arrangement of the passenger does matter in this case. For example, if Passenger A appears in the Arraylist before Passenger B. They should maintain that same order even if they both belong to the same sub-arraylist. Is there a different approach to simplify my code?

Comment: @fkaman I don't quite understand your task. Why do you need 8 different groups of passengers? If groups are needed only to assign them priority, then the problem can be solved much easier.

Comment: @chptr-one That's essentially the task. It the list simulates passengers in a queue and the have different boarding statuses hence firstGroup, secondGroup, etc.

Comment: @fkaman well, perhaps you will be curious to look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/chptr-one/5cea85ca684c900ab5daf6b431f2f2b1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this piece of code, but I think this is what you need. I just refactoring your code without diving into the details.

```
private int findGroupNumber(Passenger passenger) {                                                                                                           
     if (passenger.getType().equals("H"))                                                                                                                     
         return 1;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getRow() >= 1 && passenger.getRow() <= 4 && passenger.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("E"))                                                     
         return 2;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getRow() >= 1 && passenger.getRow() <= 4)                                                                                                  
         return 3;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("E") || passenger.getRow() == 10 || passenger.getRow() == 11)                                                   
         return 4;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getRow() >= 23 && passenger.getRow() <= 26)                                                                                                
         return 5;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getRow() >= 17 && passenger.getRow() <= 22)                                                                                                
         return 6;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getRow() >= 11 && passenger.getRow() <= 16)                                                                                                
         return 7;                                                                                                                                            
     if (passenger.getRow() >= 5 && passenger.getRow() <= 10)                                                                                                 
         return 8;                                                                                                                                            
     else                                                                                                                                                     
         throw new RuntimeException("Some error.");                                                                                                           
 }                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                              
 public void loadOldPQ(List<Passenger> list) throws IOException {                                                                                             
     List<List<Passenger>> groups = new ArrayList<>(8);                                                                                                       
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {                                                                                                                            
         groups.add(new ArrayList<>());                                                                                                                       
     }                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                              
     for (var passenger : list) {                                                                                                                             
         groups.get(findGroupNumber(passenger) - 1).add(passenger);                                                                                               
     }                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                              
     int priorityNumber = list.size();                                                                                                                        
     for (var group : groups) {                                                                                                                               
         for (var passenger : group) {                                                                                                                        
             passenger.setKey(priorityNumber--);                                                                                                              
             System.out.println(passenger);                                                                                                                   
         }                                                                                                                                                    
     }                                                                                                                                                        
 }
```